# Using wait_until with function_updated in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am newbie to Ruby, want to understand the syntax for client.wait_until.
I have a lambda client which needs to wait for function update to apply the next set of function updates. I want to use wait_until here. I have read through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Lambda/Client.html#get_function_configuration-instance_method here but still not able to figure out how this works.

Below is code sample :

```
function_config = create_or_update_lambda(lambda_config, @deployer_config.runtime)

##I have to wait till the above update finishes.
lambda_client = get_lambda_client(lambda_config)
 
lambda_client.wait_until(:function_updated,lambda_client.get_function_configuration({function_name: lambda_config.function}))

update_function_code(s3_object_version, lambda_config)
```

Comment: can you expand what is "not able to figure out how this works"? What is the error?

Comment: I was not able to understand what input params wait_until would take. But now I figured out, refer to my answer below.

Comment: glad you found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct way of calling wait_until is like this :

```
lambda_client.wait_until(:function_updated, 
function_name: function_trying_to_update_lambda[:function_name])
```

where function_trying_to_update_lambda is trying to update my lambda and is followed by another lambda update function.